# eldoc mode makes emacs use 100% cpu

Tags: emacs, cpu

When I use eldoc, I add this to `.emacs`:

```
 (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)
 (add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)
 (add-hook 'ielm-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)
```

and then when I use Emacs, it uses 100% CPU.

But when I delete this code in `.emacs`, my Emacs works.

Does anyone have any idea about this? Or how to debug the problem.

Or something else to substitute for eldoc?